# What digit positions in a different base can be potentially altered given a change in a specific digit of current base

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am not a mathematician.

I have some number $A_b$ which has a digit in a position $p$. That number can be written in another base as $V_d$ and it will have a range of digits $q_{start}$ – $q_{end}$ which hold (potentially added with other values) data from that digit.

I need to find the range $q_{start}$ – $q_{end}$.

And I can do a part of that for non-negative positions $p$ (to the left of the point) we know that the smallest non-zero digit in any base is $1$, thus $q_{start}$ is simply $\log_q\left(b^{p}\right)$ (round down), and $q_{end}$ is somewhat trivial once we bound it to $1$ in the next position, so it becomes $\log_q\left(b^{p+1}\right)$ (round up?).

However, I get completely lost once we approach digits to the right of the point. I know that in some situations $q_{end}$ will be infinite. I understand that it cannot happen when $d$ is a multiple of $b$. But somehow I am stuck.

Comment: Even for non-negative positions $p$ it's not that easy. In general, changing $p$-th digit of a number in base $b$ can affect even the most significant digit of a number in base $d$. For example two numbers ${473523889}_{11}$ and ${47352388A}_{11}$ in base $11$ differ only by the least significant digits. This change, however, makes a huge difference in base $10$ where these two numbers are written as, respectively: ${999999999}_{10}$ and ${1000000000}_{10}$.

Comment: @mwt Thanks, but as i have said i differentiate about the value of that digit and the values that it is added with due to other digits. But you're correct, i should have made it more clear.